# Generar archivo .TXT con Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo el siguiente SP y deseo que los resultados se guarden en un Archivo .TXT para 
  ello también dispongo de un JOB el cual ejecuta el Stored Procedure, el cual configuré
  desde el SQL Server Management Studio.

Este es un ejemplo de como se manda a un TXT el resultado de una consulta, y a partir de este
  ejemplo implementarlo en un Stored Procedure.

```
DECLARE @archivo varchar(50),

    @comando varchar(2000)


SET @archivo = 'E:\archivo.txt'
SET @comando = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM bdd.dbo.tblEjemplo" queryout "'
SET @comando = @comando + @archivo + '" -U sa -P 1234567 -c'


EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @comando
```

´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´

Implementacion en el Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consulta_hoy
@Hoy DATE

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @Hoy = GETDATE()

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @archivo varchar(50),@comando varchar(2000)
SET @archivo = 'E:\archivo.txt'

SET @comando = 'bcp"
SELECT c.CodeCompany, 
    @Hoy AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave, 
    c.nombre +' '+c.apellidos AS Nombre, --Me marca un error por el uso de +' '+ 
    d.Descripcion AS Depto,
    t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,
    convert(time(0), fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,
    convert(time(0), fechaSalida) AS Salida,

DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia

FROM tblasistencia a

    JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
    JOIN tblTurno    t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno
    JOIN tblDepto    d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto

WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) and fkStatus !=1 " queryout "'
SET @comando = @comando + @archivo + '" -U sa -P 123457 -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @comando

END
```

Ejecucion SP:

```
exec consulta_hoy '';
```

Cuando mando a ejecutar el Stored Procedure, muestra lo siguiente:

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
[-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
[-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
[-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
[-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
[-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
[-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
[-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
[-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
[-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
[-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
[-d database name]
NULL
```

Mandando a impresión la variable @comando

Me muestra:

```
bcp"
SELECT c.CodeCompany, 
    @Hoy AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave, 
    c.nombre  c.apellidos AS Nombre, 
    d.Descripcion AS Depto,
    t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia,
    convert(time(0), fechaEntrada) AS Entrada,
    convert(time(0), fechaSalida) AS Salida,

DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia

FROM tblasistencia a

    JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
    JOIN tblTurno    t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno
    JOIN tblDepto    d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto

WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) and fkStatus !=1 " queryout "E:\archivo.txt" -U sa -P 123457 -c
```

Comment: DB.dbo.consulta_hoy has probado asi?

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues un `PRINT @comando` y edites la pregunta con el resultado de esta sentencia. Que el bcp te muestre la ayuda seguramente es por algún parámetro que no reconoce como tal

Comment: @LuisFernando Si, ya lo intente, el resultado sigue siendo igual.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

El problema es este:

```
SET @comando = 'bcp"
SELECT c.CodeCompany,
```

Estas agregando saltos de línea a la sentencias que vas a ejecutar, estos rompen la llamada. Reescribí un poco tu código:

Algunas correcciones e indicaciones

```
DECLARE @comando VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query   VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @archivo VARCHAR(50)

SET @archivo = 'E:\archivo.txt'
SET @query   = 'SELECT c.CodeCompany, @Hoy AS fechaActual, a.idClave, C.nombre +'' ''+c.apellidos AS Nombre, d.Descripcion AS Depto, t.HorasAlDia AS HorasDia, convert(time(0), fechaEntrada) AS Entrada, convert(time(0), fechaSalida) AS Salida, DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia FROM tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave JOIN tblTurno t ON t.idTurno=c.fkTurno JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) and fkStatus !=1'

SET @comando = 'bcp queryout "'+ REPLACE(@query + '" ' + @archivo + ' -U sa -P 123457 -c'
```

- Si tienes que indicar una comilla simple en una cadena dinámica debes escribirla de la siguiente forma `''`
- Recuerda que el usuario con que inicia el servicio del SQL Server tiene que tener permisos de escritura para poder salvar el archivo.
- Revisa lo de los saltos y/o tabs.

Otra opción es quitar los saltos de línea de la sentencia, de la siguiente forma:

```
SET @query = REPLACE(REPLACE(@query, CHAR(10), ''),CHAR(13), '')
```

Doble `REPLACE` anidado para quitar los caracteres 13 y 10, el salto de línea habitual de Windows.

Comment: No sé por que me muestre aun usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]

Comment: [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]
NULL

Comment: @NetzaL, El problema de los saltos de línea sigue persistiendo en `@query`, acabo de modificar el código para evitarlo.

Comment: como termina REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement ) asi? REPLACE(query + '" ' + archivo + ' -U sa -P 123457 -c')

Comment: @NetzaL, ahí edite la respuesta, puedes hacer: `SET @query = REPLACE(REPLACE(@query, CHAR(10), ''),CHAR(13), '')` para quitar saltos de línea. Saludos

Comment: Aun me sale:                                                       Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]

Comment: de esta forma esta agregado                                                               SET query = REPLACE(REPLACE(query,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
    SET comando = 'bcp queryout "'+ query + '" ' + archivo + ' -Usa -PZxCv123 -c'